# C# SharpSSH changing SFTP port.

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp

I have a small C# app that uses the SharpSSH library to simply upload a file using SFTP. Now my client wants to use the same program to connect to another server using SSH/SFTP, however for some reason that server has been built using "SSH/SFTP over custom port 5929." No idea why they changed the port, however..

I have looked over all the documentation that I can find for SharpSSH but can find no mention of how I could direct it to use port 5929 vice the normal port 22.  My thought would be to use HOSTNAME:5929 but not sure if that is correct.

Anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 3):

`SshTransferProtocolBase` has a connect method with 1 overloads. The defalut one takes no argument and defaults to port 22. The overload takes a port number.

So:

```
SshTransferProtocolBase ftp = new SshTransferProtocolBase("host","user");
ftp.connect(5929);
```

The above should work.

Answer (score 3):

`Tamir.SharpSsh` has one overload for Connect() method, which accepts an integer and allows the port to be set.

```
Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp sftpClient = new Sftp(sftpServer, sftpUserName, sftpUserPassword);    
sftpClient.Connect(sftpPort);   
sftpClient.Close();
sftpClient = null;
```